# express static with multiple routes returning 404

Tags: express

I'm serving up two create-react apps.

This works navigating to localhost:9000/

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, APP_STATIC_PATH)));
```

But this doesn't work when I navigate to localhost:9000/app

```
app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, APP_STATIC_PATH)));
```

I get a bunch of `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` for all my .css and .js files

How can I change the create react app public url to point to the correct static dic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's running into the same problem.

In package.json you can set your homepage:'/app' and create react-app will use that on yarn build.